# Reference request: Commutator relations for the exceptional group F4

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups, exceptional-groups, chevalley-groups

Is there any standard reference for the commutator relations for the exceptional group of type $F_4$?

If this question is not appropriate here, please let me know and I will delete it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can deduce them from the Cartan matrix and the [Chevalley-Serre relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system_of_a_semi-simple_Lie_algebra#The_relations).

Comment: @Spenser Thanks for the comment. But I am a little worried about the last 2 relations. What is exactly $ad_{X_\lambda}(X_\mu)$? In the group version, what are the constants? In other words, let $x_\lambda$ be the corresponding unipotent element, and it is known that $[x_\lambda(r), x_{\mu}(s)]=\prod_{i,j>0}x_{i\lambda +j\mu}(c_{ij}r^is^j)$, what are exactly those $c_{ij}$? I could not see that from the Chevalley-Serre relations. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't realize you were seeking relations in the group rather than the Lie algebra. I don't know what you are looking for then.